# Manning Spring , Hibernate Cover Image

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Not sure if this is the right forum as this is not a technical question but I am quite intrigued about the cover image of the famous Manning in Spring , Hibernate books. What does that image signify? I cannot relate  that image with java technology. Any inputs from anyone as why the publisher uses the image of a man with some dress and stick (Apologies as I don't know what kind of outfit is that).

That man belongs to which culture and is it that the author is any way related to that culture? Curiosity is killing this bird. Help me !!

Comment: @ metalhead good question but not sure whether this one is the right place. it may be the style of writer or different purpose that he want to give. if you look on spring in action i think the dress he is wearing is like a unique kind this may be indicating that the book is unique and also the vessel he is carrying means want to offer somebody who is interested . just as an example....

Comment: yes Spring in Action 2, 3 & Manning Java persistence with Hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Spring in Action #1

> The figure of the cover page of *Spring in Action* is an "**Officer of the
>   Grand Signior**". The illustration is taken from a collection of
>   costumes of the Ottoman Empire published on January 1, 1802, by
>   William Miller of Old Bond Street, London.

For Spring in Action #2 and #3

> The figure on the cover of *Spring in Action*, Third Edition, is a “**Le
>   Caraco**”, or an inhabitant of the province of Karak in southwest
>   Jordan. Its capital is the city of Al-Karak, which boasts an ancient
>   hilltop castle with magnificent views of the Dead Sea and surrounding
>   plains. The illustration is taken from a French travel book,
>   *Encyclopédie des Voyages* by J. G. St. Sauveur, published in 1796.
>   Travel for pleasure was a relatively new phenomenon at the time and
>   travel guides such as this one were popular, introducing both the
>   tourist as well as the armchair traveler to the inhabitants of other
>   regions of France and abroad.

The book also says that for a short reason of why these images:

> We at Manning celebrate the inventiveness, the initiative, and the fun
>   of the computer business with book covers based on the rich diversity
>   of regional life two centuries ago brought back to life by the
>   pictures from this travel guide.

It is said the same in all Maning books I have, for example in the AspectJ in Action the cover comes from:

> The figure on the cover of AspectJ in Action is an “Ysleno Moluco,” an
>   inhabitant of the Molucan Islands, also known as the Spice Islands, a
>   southwestern province of Indonesia. The illustration is taken from a
>   Spanish compendium of regional dress customs first published in Madrid
>   in 1799.

And the same explanations as above is given.

Comment: Thanks for this info but why would the author use this particular image? What should the readers make out of it? Is there something we the readers are missing or just ignorant ?

Answer (score 0):

Explaination is given in respective books. Check books.

For e.g. **Spring in Action**, I pasted as it is from the book : The figure on the cover of Spring in Action, Third Edition, is a “Le Caraco,” or an inhab-
itant of the province of Karak in southwest Jordan. Its capital is the city of Al-Karak,
which boasts an ancient hilltop castle with magnificent views of the Dead Sea and sur-
rounding plains.
The illustration is taken from a French travel book, Encyclopédie des Voyages by J. G.
St. Sauveur, published in 1796. Travel for pleasure was a relatively new phenomenon
at the time and travel guides such as this one were popular, introducing both the tour-
ist as well as the armchair traveler to the inhabitants of other regions of France and
abroad.
The diversity of the drawings in the Encyclopédie des Voyages speaks vividly of the
uniqueness and individuality of the world’s towns and provinces just 200 years ago.
This was a time when the dress codes of two regions separated by a few dozen miles
identified people uniquely as belonging to one or the other. The travel guide brings
to life a sense of isolation and distance of that period and of every other historic
period except our own hyperkinetic present.
Dress codes have changed since then and the diversity by region, so rich at the
time, has faded away. It is now often hard to tell the inhabitant of one continent from
another. Perhaps, trying to view it optimistically, we have traded a cultural and visual
diversity for a more varied personal life. Or a more varied and interesting intellectual
and technical life.
We at Manning celebrate the inventiveness, the initiative, and the fun of the com-
puter business with book covers based on the rich diversity of regional life two centu-
ries ago brought back to life by the pictures from this travel guide.

Comment: "We at Manning celebrate the inventiveness, the initiative, and the fun of the com- puter business with book covers based on the rich diversity of regional life two centu- ries ago brought back to life by the pictures from this travel guide" This sheds some light on the intentionof the publisher .. thanks!!